# Drag and Drop on GridView and Item

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

Thanks in advance.

I want a function，then I got it, like this:

[image]

But like that picture, In GridView have item and Folder(like favorite),I need Drag items into Folder, like this:

[image]

but, I have two method:

In `GridView`:

```
AllowDrop="True"
DragOver="girdView_DragOver"
Drop="girdView_Drop"
```

In `Folder`(it is a StackPanel)：

```
Drop="StackPanel_Drop" AllowDrop="True" DragOver="StackPanel_DragOver"
```

but I have a problem:

**When I Drag a Item, I drag on gridview, potential drop target is gridview, so invoke gridview's `DragOver`, But I drag on Folder, though Folder is potential drop target, but because it is in gridview, Still invoke gridview's `DragOver` **

How to invoke Folder's `DragOver`? such as some priority thing.

and:

When I drop on Folder, will invoke both `Drop` method.

such as:

[image]

this will invoke gridview's `drop` and Folder's `drop`.

How to Solve this problem？

thanks

Comment: What is the specific requirement that you need the folder `DragOver` event in a `GridView`? And do you just want the Folder's drop?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT yes , I mean that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need drag items to gridview or a folder that in gridvew.

but I when I drop, will Trigger the event of both.

I solved it this way:

as Breeze Liu - MSFT's inspiration:

> You can also register the DragOver event with same event handler name then distinguish the event by the event handler sender object as the following code

In GridView:
set the `Drop = "DragOver"`

In Folder(it is a StackPanel)：
set the `Drop = "DragOver"` too.

and handler :

**You should declare a var to record**

**If you drop in stackpanel, because the StackPanel is in GridView, so sender is StackPanel and GridView, it will though both decide if (It is werid)**

if drop in stackpanel,

so you should do this:

```
int flag = 0;
private void DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is StackPanel)
    {
        flag = 1;
        //TODO StackPanel DragOver
        Debug.WriteLine(sender.GetType().ToString());
    }else if(sender is GridView && flag == 0)
    {
        //TODO GridView DragOver
        Debug.WriteLine(sender.GetType().ToString());
    }
    flag = 0;
}
```

hope helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_DragOver),

> Occurs when the input system reports an underlying drag event with this element as the potential drop target.

If you just want the folder (`StackPanel`)'s `DragOver` event, you can set the `GridView` `AllowDrop` property is **false**, then the GridView's `DragOver` event will not trigger.

On other way, if you don't need the `DragOver` event of the `GridView`, why not delete GridView's event registration. You can also register the `DragOver` event with same event handler name then distinguish the event by the event handler `sender` object as the following code, so as the `Drop` event.

```
private void DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is StackPanel)
    {
        //TODO StackPanel DragOver
        Debug.WriteLine(sender.GetType().ToString());
    }else if(sender is GridView)
    {
        //TODO GridView DragOver
        Debug.WriteLine(sender.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I mean, I want drop items to Group or a Folder in Group. when I drop in folder, It will invoke GridView and StackPanel's two DropEvent. This is a conflict. I tried use one DragOver method to GridView and StackPanel, but I don't want it.